# Jfreechart in chartpanel in jPanel not displaying

Tags: jpanel, jfreechart, visible

I have created JFreeChart and put it into chartpanel (as was suggested). I also added it to a jPanel. I'm using the jFrame. But my chart is not visible after running the program. Can anyone help me, please?

```
final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
        "XY Series Demo",
        "iterácie", 
        "%", 
        data,
        PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
        true,
        true,
        false
    );

    final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
    //chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 270));
    chartPanel.setDomainZoomable(true);
    chartPanel.setVisible(true);
    jPanel1.add(chartPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: Invoking `setVisible(true)` after `pack()` on the enclosing `JFrame` should be sufficient. If not, please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: OK, so I added runnable code..

Comment: ALternatively, you can `pack()` the enclosing `Window`. You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/163188).

Answer (score 0):

(Answered in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [What is the appropriate action when the answer to a question is added to the question itself?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que) )

The OP wrote:

> [SOLVED] I was missing these two:
>
> ```
> jPanel1.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());
> jPanel1.validate();
> ```